# DNS resolving broken after installation of bind due to iptables

Tags: dns, firewall, iptables, bind, nameserver

I successfully configured my web server (Apache, PHP etc.)
and blocked the ports I don't need using iptables, which was
working perfectly fine.

Today, I installed BIND and configured it, which also works.
The only thing that stopped working was DNS resolving on my server itself.
I'm 100% sure it's due to the iptables configuration, because when
I reset the configuration, everything works fine. When I set the iptables
configuration to the configuration I used before I installed BIND, however,
the whole thing still does not work.

I added the following rules for DNS:

```
# Loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT   #Allow loopback access from INPUT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT  #Allow loopback access from OUTPUT

# DNS
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: DNS uses TCP on port 53 too.

Comment: I tried added TCP, too, but still no dice. Does something change to the port configuration when you install BIND?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using bits of the tutorial described here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-12-how-to-block-or-open-dnsbind-service-port-53.html